# How can `Get-Command` return "commands" that aren't really commands?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

'Get-Command' returns a list of all available commands in a powershell session.

The following code evaluates to $false, when passed a string which is not a command:

```
function f($x) {[bool](Get-Command $x -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)}
```

And it does:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> f ls
True
PS C:\Windows\system32> f alkdsjfasd
False
```

So you would think that the following code would return the list of commands which are not commands -- that is an empty list:

```
Get-Command | Where-Object {[bool](Get-Command $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $false}
```

Except it doesn't.  It returns the following on a clean Windows Server 2016 VM:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Get-IseSnippet                                     1.0.0.0    ISE
Function        Import-IseSnippet                                  1.0.0.0    ISE
Function        New-IseSnippet                                     1.0.0.0    ISE
Function        Start-AutologgerConfig                             1.0.0.0    EventTracingManagement
Cmdlet          Add-ClusteriSCSITargetServerRole                   2.0.0.0    IscsiTarget
```

If I wait a little while and run the same command again, it returns a much longer list:

```
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Function        Add-RDServer                                       2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
Function        Add-RDSessionHost                                  2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
Function        Add-RDVirtualDesktopToCollection                   2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
Function        Disable-RDVirtualDesktopADMachineAccountReuse      2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
Function        Get-IseSnippet                                     1.0.0.0    ISE
...
Function        Test-RDVirtualDesktopADMachineAccountReuse         2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
Function        Update-RDVirtualDesktopCollection                  2.0.0.0    RemoteDesktop
```

I've checked the files in the RemoteDesktop module, for example, and I've been able to find the functions that are "missing".

What is going on here?  How can 'Get-Command' return "commands" that aren't commands?

Comment: what happens if you run the commands after a period of time on the command line using the -noprofile flag?

Comment: Hmmm ... I'm not sure if I got what the actual question is. `Get-Command` returns cmdlets, functions and aliasses ... all that depending on the underlying OS and installed modules and products

Comment: @Ctznkane525 The behavior is identical whether or not I start powershell with the -NoProfile switch.  The first run outputs a few commands, the second outputs many more.

Comment: @Olaf It's true that the output of Get-Command is different on different computers, but the output of 'gcm | where {[bool](gcm $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $false}' should always be nothing.  No matter what system it's run on.  It's like if I take a list of all the files in a folder, and then remove each file that's in the folder, I should be left with an empty list, no matter what folder I do that with.

Comment: I can't fully account for it, but `get-command` lists available commands, including modules which are not imported. `get-command $_` triggers module auto-import. For one example, the `webadministration` module on my system claims it will export `Begin-WebCommitDelay` as an alias, during import as a normal user it errors because I'm not an admin and cannot access IIS configuration data, and then whatever happens it does not export that alias at all and get-command no longer shows it. I suspect the delay of modules auto-importing, and the change of state during import is involved in this.